# Unable to resize QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

I m trying to resize a table widget inside a QVBoxlayout which I further add as a row to a QFormlayout in pyqt

I m currently adding a QVboxlayout which contains a table widget inside it as a row in a Qformlayout.

And the main aim is to strecth the Table widget till the end of the application window that it acquires the left over space on the window

Using the below code -

```
class PGSearchDetails():

    def __init__(self,parent=None):

         self.widget_pgsd = QWidget()
         self.layout_pgsd = QFormLayout()
         self.layout_pgsd.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QFormLayout.FieldGrowthPolicy(2|1))
         self.PG_Id = QLineEdit()
         #rx = QRegExp("^\\D+[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,(,),:,\",{,},?,<,>,|,+,-,~,]")
         #rx = QRegExp(" (?!(@,#,$|%|\^|&|*|(|)|:|\"|{|}|?|<|>|\||+|-|~|!))[\\w]+")
         str_rx = QRegExp("^[A-Za-z*]{20}(?!@#$%^&*():\"\{\}?<>\|+-~!_-)")
         adhr_rx = QRegExp("[A-Z0-9]{12}(?!@#$%^&*():\"\{\}?<>\|+-~!_)")

         val = QRegExpValidator(str_rx)
         val3 = QRegExpValidator(adhr_rx)

         self.PG_Id.setValidator(val3)
         self.LastName = QLineEdit()
         self.LastName.setValidator(val)
         self.MobNum = QLineEdit()
         qint_val = QIntValidator()
         qint_val.setTop(10)
         self.MobNum.setValidator(qint_val)


         self.layout_pgsd.addRow("First Name",self.PG_Id)
         self.layout_pgsd.addRow("Last Name",self.LastName)
         self.layout_pgsd.addRow("Mobile Number",self.MobNum)

         update_layout_pgsd = QHBoxLayout()

         layout_test,table = dbv.Search_View(self.getT)

         #layout_test.setGeometry(QRect(200,200,50,50))

         #table.setMaximumHeight(800)
         #table.setGeometry(200,200,200,200)
         #table.setGeometry(1,1,1000,600)
         table.resize(1000,600)

         update_btn_pgsd = QPushButton('Update')
         reset_btn_pgsd = QPushButton('Reset')

         update_layout_pgsd.addWidget(update_btn_pgsd)
         update_layout_pgsd.addWidget(reset_btn_pgsd)

         self.layout_pgsd.addRow(update_layout_pgsd)

         ##Adding the Table Widget to FormLayot
         self.layout_pgsd.addRow(layout_test)
         update_btn_pgsd.clicked.connect(partial(self.database,table,self.MobNum,
                                                         self.LastName))
         #self.widget.setLayout(self.layout_pgsd)


    def returnLayout(self):
        return self.layout_pgsd

    def returnWidget(self):
        return self.widget_pgsd

    def getT(self,linedit):
        print("LE--->",linedit.text())
```

QtableWidget setup ---

```
def Search_View(self):

    print("Inside Search_view")


    central_widget = QWidget()              # Create a central widget
    db_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    #col_count = len(self.pg_details.__dict__.keys())
    col_count = 3

    table = QTableWidget()  # Create a table
    #central_widget.setGeometry(200,200,150,150)
    #table.maximumSize()
    #db_layout.setMaximumSize(200)
    db_layout.setGeometry(QRect(0,0,100,30))


    db_layout.addWidget(table)


    ##Tried resizing the Table widget but nothing seems to works
    table.resize(1000,600)
    table.setGeometry(0,2,1000,600)

    #central_widget.resize(central_widget.sizeHint())

    #central_widget.setColumnWidth(1000,600)

    #db_layout.addItem(update_layout)

    central_widget.setLayout(db_layout)

    print("Geometry  H--->",table.geometry().height())
    print("Geometry  W--->",table.geometry().width())
    print("Geometry  X--->",table.geometry().x())
    print("Geometry  Y--->",table.geometry().y())



    return central_widget,table
```

After the resize function, The table geometry changes to 1000,600 but on the screen it is not reflected. On the app screen it remains the same size everytime

Also find the entire code which contains the Tablayouts as well and Stacked widget for individual radio buttons

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.tab_widget = MainTabWindow()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)
        self.show()



class MainTabWindow(QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainTabWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Tab Example')

        self.tab1 = QWidget()

        self.addTab(self.tab1,"Search")


        self.PGSearchTab()


    def PGSearchTab(self):
      print("Search Tab First Tab")
      self.central_layout = QVBoxLayout()

      self.stack1 = QWidget()
      self.stack2 = QWidget()
      self.stack3 = QWidget()

      self.stack_widget = QStackedWidget()

      button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
      radio_button_1 = QRadioButton("Search")
      radio_button_2 = QRadioButton("Add")
      radio_button_3 = QRadioButton("Update")

      button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_1)
      button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_2)
      button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_3)

      self.central_layout.addItem(button_layout)

      self.stack_widget.addWidget(self.stack1)
      self.stack_widget.addWidget(self.stack2)
      self.stack_widget.addWidget(self.stack3)


      self.central_layout.addWidget(self.stack_widget)

      radio_button_1.toggled.connect(lambda :self.SelectButtonCheck(radio_button_1))

      self.setTabText(0,"Search")

      update_layout = QHBoxLayout()

      update_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
      update_btn = QPushButton('Update')
      reset_btn = QPushButton('Reset')


      update_layout.addWidget(update_btn)
      update_layout.addWidget(reset_btn)

      self.tab1.setLayout(self.central_layout)


    def SelectButtonCheck(self,b):
        if b.text() == "Search":
            if b.isChecked():
                print(b.text()+ "is selected")
                self.obj_pgsd = pgsd.PGSearchDetails()
                layout = self.obj_pgsd.returnLayout()
                if self.stack1.layout() is None:
                    self.stack1.setLayout(layout)

                self.stack_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)


def main():

    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainTabWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I do not seem to understand what is I m missing here

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Also find the working code to execute the above layout setup.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget,QMainWindow,QLineEdit,QAction,
                            QLabel,QPushButton,QVBoxLayout,
                            QTabWidget,QFormLayout,QHBoxLayout,
                            QRadioButton,QCheckBox,QTextEdit,
                            QListView,QDialogButtonBox,QSizePolicy,QCalendarWidget)
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import PyQt5.Qt
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtSql
from functools import partial


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.tab_widget = MainTabWindow()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)
        self.show()



class MainTabWindow(QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainTabWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Tab Example')

        self.tab1 = QWidget()

        self.addTab(self.tab1,"Search")


        self.PGSearchTab()


    def PGSearchTab(self):
      print("Search Tab First Tab")
      self.central_layout = QVBoxLayout()

      self.stack1 = QWidget()
      self.stack2 = QWidget()
      self.stack3 = QWidget()

      self.stack_widget = QStackedWidget()

      button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
      radio_button_1 = QRadioButton("Search")
      radio_button_2 = QRadioButton("Add")
      radio_button_3 = QRadioButton("Update")

      button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_1)
      button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_2)
      button_layout.addWidget(radio_button_3)

      self.central_layout.addItem(button_layout)

      self.stack_widget.addWidget(self.stack1)
      self.stack_widget.addWidget(self.stack2)
      self.stack_widget.addWidget(self.stack3)


      self.central_layout.addWidget(self.stack_widget)

      radio_button_1.toggled.connect(lambda :self.SelectButtonCheck(radio_button_1))

      self.setTabText(0,"Search")

      update_layout = QHBoxLayout()

      update_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
      update_btn = QPushButton('Update')
      reset_btn = QPushButton('Reset')


      update_layout.addWidget(update_btn)
      update_layout.addWidget(reset_btn)

      self.tab1.setLayout(self.central_layout)


    def SelectButtonCheck(self,b):
        if b.text() == "Search":
            if b.isChecked():
                print(b.text()+ "is selected")
                self.obj_pgsd = PGSearchDetails()
                layout = self.obj_pgsd.returnLayout()
                if self.stack1.layout() is None:
                    self.stack1.setLayout(layout)

                self.stack_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)


class PGSearchDetails():

    def __init__(self,parent=None):

         self.widget_pgsd = QWidget()
         self.layout_pgsd = QFormLayout()
         self.layout_pgsd.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QFormLayout.FieldGrowthPolicy(2|1))
         self.PG_Id = QLineEdit()
         #rx = QRegExp("^\\D+[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,(,),:,\",{,},?,<,>,|,+,-,~,]")
         #rx = QRegExp(" (?!(@,#,$|%|\^|&|*|(|)|:|\"|{|}|?|<|>|\||+|-|~|!))[\\w]+")
         str_rx = QRegExp("^[A-Za-z*]{20}(?!@#$%^&*():\"\{\}?<>\|+-~!_-)")
         adhr_rx = QRegExp("[A-Z0-9]{12}(?!@#$%^&*():\"\{\}?<>\|+-~!_)")

         val = QRegExpValidator(str_rx)
         val3 = QRegExpValidator(adhr_rx)

         self.PG_Id.setValidator(val3)
         self.LastName = QLineEdit()
         self.LastName.setValidator(val)
         self.MobNum = QLineEdit()
         qint_val = QIntValidator()
         qint_val.setTop(10)
         self.MobNum.setValidator(qint_val)


         self.layout_pgsd.addRow("First Name",self.PG_Id)
         self.layout_pgsd.addRow("Last Name",self.LastName)
         self.layout_pgsd.addRow("Mobile Number",self.MobNum)

         update_layout_pgsd = QHBoxLayout()

         layout_test,table = self.Search_View(self.getT)

         #layout_test.setGeometry(QRect(200,200,50,50))

         #table.setMaximumHeight(800)
         #table.setGeometry(200,200,200,200)
         #table.setGeometry(1,1,1000,600)
         table.resize(1000,600)

         update_btn_pgsd = QPushButton('Update')
         reset_btn_pgsd = QPushButton('Reset')

         update_layout_pgsd.addWidget(update_btn_pgsd)
         update_layout_pgsd.addWidget(reset_btn_pgsd)

         self.layout_pgsd.addRow(update_layout_pgsd)

         ##Adding the Table Widget to FormLayot
         self.layout_pgsd.addRow(layout_test)
         update_btn_pgsd.clicked.connect(partial(self.database,table,self.MobNum,
                                                         self.LastName))
         #self.widget.setLayout(self.layout_pgsd)


    def returnLayout(self):
        return self.layout_pgsd

    def returnWidget(self):
        return self.widget_pgsd

    def getT(self,linedit):
        print("LE--->",linedit.text())

    def Search_View(self,text):

        print("Inside Search_view")


        central_widget = QWidget()              # Create a central widget
        db_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        #col_count = len(self.pg_details.__dict__.keys())
        col_count = 3

        table = QTableWidget()  # Create a table
        #central_widget.setGeometry(200,200,150,150)
        #table.maximumSize()
        #db_layout.setMaximumSize(200)
        db_layout.setGeometry(QRect(0,0,100,30))


        db_layout.addWidget(table)


        ##Tried resizing the Table widget but nothing seems to works
        table.resize(1000,600)
        table.setGeometry(0,2,1000,600)

        #central_widget.resize(central_widget.sizeHint())

        #central_widget.setColumnWidth(1000,600)

        #db_layout.addItem(update_layout)

        central_widget.setLayout(db_layout)

        print("Geometry  H--->",table.geometry().height())
        print("Geometry  W--->",table.geometry().width())
        print("Geometry  X--->",table.geometry().x())
        print("Geometry  Y--->",table.geometry().y())



        return central_widget,table

    def SqlExec(self,text):
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
        db.setHostName('localhost')
        db.setDatabaseName('Test')
        db.setUserName('root')
        db.open()

        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        select = "select * from Test.PG_Details where PG_Id=?"# where PG_Id = 1"
        query.prepare(select)
        indexes = range(3)
        print("TEXT----->",text)
        query.addBindValue(text)
        #query.exec_(select)
        query.exec_()

        print("Sizze----",query.size())
        row_count = query.size()
        db.record('PG_Details')

        col_list = []

        for i in range(db.record('PG_Details').count()):
            print("FIELD----->",db.record('PG_Details').field(i).name())
            col_list.append(db.record('PG_Details').field(i).name())

        db.close()

        return query,row_count,col_list


    def database(self,table,text,text2):

        text = text.text()
        query_result,row_count,col_list = self.SqlExec(text)

        i = 0
        table.setColumnCount(3)     #Set three columns
        table.setRowCount(row_count)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(col_list)
        while query_result.next():
            #print(query_result.value(i))
            result_row = [query_result.value(index) for index in range(query_result.record().count())]
            #print("RR--->",result_row)
            for idx,val in enumerate(result_row):
                #print("IDX----->",idx)
                table.setItem(i, idx, QTableWidgetItem(val))
            i = i + 1



def main():

    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainTabWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc - I m combining QFormLayout with QVboxlayout that contains a Tablewidget inside it. Which i m trying to resize

Comment: The fact is that your code is not correct and if I can not reproduce it, it will be impossible for me to help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc- I have added the tablayout code as well.

Comment: Then I could copy, paste and execute your code without problems?

Comment: @eyllanesc - yeah 95% it would work , slight modification would be required in Qstackwidget under the PGSearchtab function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174221/discussion-between-vaibhav-sharma-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: I want 100%, when you show a [mcve] I will try to help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc - I have made the required changes, You will be able to execute the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that QFormLayout makes every time you add a widget using addRow () uses strech, the solution is to use a QVBoxLayout, and in that QVBoxLayout is to pass the QFormLayout and the layout_test.

```
class PGSearchDetails():
    def __init__(self,parent=None):

         self.widget_pgsd = QWidget()
         self.layout = QVBoxLayout() # <---
         self.layout_pgsd = QFormLayout()
         self.layout.addLayout(self.layout_pgsd) # <---
         self.layout_pgsd.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QFormLayout.FieldGrowthPolicy(2|1))
         ...

         self.layout_pgsd.addRow(update_layout_pgsd)

         ##Adding the Table Widget to FormLayot
         # self.layout_pgsd.addRow(layout_test)
         self.layout.addWidget(layout_test) # <---
         update_btn_pgsd.clicked.connect(partial(self.database,table,self.MobNum,
                                                         self.LastName))


    def returnLayout(self):
        return self.layout # <---
```

[image]